# Background Audio for a Call in Progress - Possible?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am writing a android  app which is supposed to **play back a audio file when a call is in progress**  coming from a specific number .. I tried many approaches.. but all went in vein

1. Separate Thread
2. Listener on Telephone service
3. starting a service in parallel

can any one please help me how to proceed regarding this ?

**Update :**

I am able to play a mp3 file on call recieve and i am able to play it load on speaker.. but how ever loud i play the calling party is not able to listen to it.... is there anyway i can push the speaker stream to call stream

Comment: try setting the audio stream type for MediaPlayer to AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM

Answer (score 2):

From the api doc [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output
>   device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth
>   headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during
>   a call.

So from this and lots of other so answers we can conclude that we can not play an audio during a call process.

But a long time ago from a personal experience with a handset I got a result where the audiotrack was playing while there was a call established and both the voices were heard at the same time. So I think this depends on handsets if it allows it then you can play.

You can try another thing experimentally. play the audio using a different route ( speakerphone or bluetooth).

Another option is to build your custom android build