# Is it possible to play audio during dialing state in android / ios

Tags: android, ios, audio, android-mediaplayer, phone-call

I'm trying to play some audio file on both Android & iOS on outgoing call during the dialing state and turn it of when the call is answered. 
I've found that it's not possible to do it during a call ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28091986/2510446)) but is the dialing state considered as a call?
troubling to find any documentation on this topic, how can I make it possible?